# How to input an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, input

How to input an array in C++? input - 2 3 56. need to store in array A[0]=2, A[1]=3, A[2]=56?

Comment: @chris Nothing, apparently.

Answer (score 4):

```
vector<int> v;
copy(istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator<int>(), back_inserter(v));
```

Or if you can do it at the time the vector is constructed, it's just one line (thanks to @chris):

```
vector<int> v(istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator<int>());
```

Comment: The copy is redundant. Just initialize it with the iterators.

Comment: This is not, technically, an array though.

Comment: Good idea, I've updated it now.

Comment: Now you have the most vexing parse :D Happened to me not long ago >.> And no, I didn't think of that with my first comment, so I didn't deliberately lure you into that trap.

Comment: @chris: Indeed, as tempting as this construction sounds, it's really awkward to write. Also, I would feel bad for silently discarding errors, and I'd probably want to warn you if you didn't consume the entire input. (I think in this case that can be added easily, though, with something like `cin >> ws; if (cin.get() != EOF) { /* warn */ }`.

Comment: @KerrekSB, Yeah, and I still do like the idea of just declaring the iterators together on the line above. That error checking approach should be enough unless you specifically need to redo each input one at a time until enough are there.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler to comprehend that the one with `back_inserter`:

```
std::vector<int> V;
int Temp;

while (cin >> Temp)
    V.push_back(Temp);
```

Note that we aren't using statically allocated array, because you didn't really specify how many elements you are going to read, and in that case it's usually better and safer to use `vector`.

Comment: Variables are not to be named starting with CAPS. Also I still feel like the OP wasn't necessarily asking about `vector`

Comment: *Variables are not to be named starting with CAPS* Please show me, @Boris, where it isn't allowed or recommended to do so by any credible source; it's quite the same as opening curly braces - a **convention**.

Comment: Yo know pretty well I can forward you to quite many sources. However, additional question for you: how do you distinguish a class named `V` or `Temp` from your variables? What if you call a static method?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev I use `C` prefix for class names.

Comment: It is customary to reserve ALL_UPPERCASE for macros, but that's the only reason I can think of why I don't name variables in uppercase. The wording "not to be named..." is way too strong though, it's not like the uppercase character is preceeded with just an underscore, which would be an error.